# Can't write to file c#

Tags: c#

I have a loop which scans for xml files, when success it get in to loop and manipulate strings. Problem is i can't write post because i got warning file in use. How do i fix this?

Loop:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Projektdata");
foreach (var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{            
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(file.DirectoryName + @"\"  + file))
    { 
      . . . .
```

Section to write file:

```
string directoryPath = file.DirectoryName + @"\" + file;

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(directoryPath);

writer.WriteLine(source);                                              

writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it in a `using` directive:

```
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(directoryPath))
{
    writer.WriteLine(source);                                              
}
```

If the error still occurs, try to save the `string` into a variable, and use this writing process outside of the scope of the `foreach` iterations. (Since the `foreach` iteration reads the file line by line, so it means the file is open.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to an open file. You already opened the same file for reading.

```
File.ReadLines(file.DirectoryName + @"\"  + file);
```

and

```
string directoryPath = file.DirectoryName + @"\" + file;
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(directoryPath);
```

`File.ReadLines()` is returning an `IEnumerable<string>` and will yield each line. So within the loop, the file is still open. Assumed that the writing is within the loop.